# React Navigation + React Native Web - Navigating to same screen multiple times in drawer navigator does not add to browser history

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web, react-navigation-drawer

I am using React Navigation v5 with React Native Web to create a chat UI similar to Slack, Discord, Messages for Web, etc. I'm using Drawer Navigator with custom drawer content containing links to a `Chat` screen passing a param for the chat ID. Using `linking` on the NavigationContainer, clicking each link changes the browser URL to `/chat/:id`. The problem I am facing is that each navigation to a different chat URL does not add to the browser history, so using the browser back button navigates the user wherever they were before clicking the first chat URL - they are not able to use the browser back button to cycle back through their previously selected chats.

I suspect this is related to how `navigation.navigate()` reuses an existing screen if you navigate to the same screen with different params ([source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times)). An alternative might be to use `navigation.push()`, but I haven't been able to get this working within a drawer context and would also hesitate to keep pushing new screens onto the stack as the user is navigating back and forth between different chats.

Example of my drawer navigator:

```
<Drawer.Navigator 
  openByDefault
  drawerType='permanent'
  drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props />}
>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Within `DrawerContent`, there is a `FlatList` of chat items, each with an `onPress` handler such as:

```
const onPress = (chatId) => {
  navigation.navigate('Chat', {id: chatId});
};
```

The drawer navigator itself is a screen within a Stack Navigator:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="Chats" component={ChatNavigator} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Anyone have any advice on this approach? Is there a way I can use the existing behaviour of the drawer navigator on web while being able to navigate to the same screen multiple times with different params with full browser history support?

Comment: Did you find any workaroud?

Comment: @skbvc how was your web app in the end? I met the same problem too, I prefer the behaviour of .push() compared to .navigate() but there are performance issues when I update the context as all screens rerender. Interested to know if you found a way to move forward